# Change picture box picture

Tags: c#, winforms

I added picture box to my form and import 2 pictures, from properties under `image` property i choose the first picture when the application starting and inside my `start button event` i want to change my picture to the other picture.
this is what i have try:

```
pbIndicator.Image = Image.FromFile(@"..\Resources\indicator_green.png");
```

but file not found exception error occurs.

Comment: The location is from my Recources.resx

Comment: If it's a resource (just update namespace) do this: **pbIndicator.Image = Properties.Resources.indicator_green;** Resources _won't be copied to output directory_ (and you do not even need to do it because they'll be embedded in your executable because referenced in resources.resx).

Comment: Show us the url for the first picture and the url you using to load the second picture.

Comment: You defeat the purpose of using `Recources`. take a look at Shadow Wizard's answerr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
pbIndicator.Image = Resources.indicator_green;
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that in the property window if the `Build Action` is on `Content`, and `Copy to Output Directory` is on `Copy if newer`.

If you want it to be content. Else use the answer *Shadow Wizard* gave.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comment if `indicator_green.jpg` is an image included as resource via resource file (`Resources.resx`) then it won't be copied to output directory (it means it's in your project folder because it's used to build executable but it'll be embedded inside your assembly, not deployed standalone).

Resource files will (by default) place resources you add inside `Resources` folder (and then linked). You can always access them using generated code file for resources:

```
pbIndicator.Image = Properties.Resources.indicator_green;
```

You may change namespace `Properties` and property name according to what you have in your project (by default property name has the same name of the resource and then same name as original file).

Of course you're not forced to embed your resources in your assembly. If you want to deploy them as standalone files just right click Resources folder and add an existing file. In the properties window for that file select Copy always for Copy to output directory and et voila, you'll be able to read it with:

```
pbIndicator.Image = Image.FromFile(@"Resources\indicator_green.png");
```

Please note that `Resources` folder won't be a sub-directory of your output directory (do not forget that source files are not part of installation).

Anyway I suggest you do not build path like that, little bit better would be to do not rely on current folder:

```
pbIndicator.Image = Image.FromFile(
    Path.Combine(Application.StartupFolder, @"Resources\indicator_green.png");
```

You're not limited to `Resources` folder, you can do that with any folder (and with any name).